# is it necessary to install JDK to run java code in atom text editor?

Tags: java, atom-editor, javac

I am using windows 10 and I installed atom text editor and script package.
when I run a java code it shows error.

"'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Unless you expect Atom itself to include a compiler for any language it supports, I guess that yes you need a JDK.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://ide.atom.io/, you need a "Java 8 runtime".

And if Atom is telling you that it cannot find `javac`, then it most likely requires a Java 8 JDK ... rather than a JRE.

Answer (score 0):

yes. it's necessary to download JDK to run java in atom text editor.

required packages are :
1.script
2.platefrorm-ide-terminal

how ever you need atom text editor and jdk compulsary.

i got a good information from this website.
refer the website: https://ozanecare.com/how-to-run-java-program-in-atom-editor/

Answer (score 0):

You need JDK to develop applications in Java.

To edit or add new Environment Variables, Insert the address at the beginning of var. Path  i.e C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin

• Right click start menu, select System, go to About, and then select System Info under Related Settings.

• Click on the Advanced system settings link and then click Environment Variables. Under the section System Variables, select the environment variable you want to edit, and click Edit.

• If the environment variable you want doesn't exist, click New.

• Input the value of the environment variable in the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, and click OK.